# Programmatically share folder with multiple users

Tags: dropbox-api

I am building app which in which i want to create folder under the app folder. 
Hierarchy
  app
   --project1
   --project2

Now i want to share project1 folder with user1 and user2.
At the same time project2 folder will be shared with user3 and user4.

I could not find any API. Can any body help?

Comment: yes it is possible ! take a look at this link https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#shares and since you have not mentioned about the platform , i can't help you programmatically ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Dropbox API currently doesn't offer any calls for managing shares folders, and in addition, app folders are incompatible with shared folders. In this case, you'll need to use 'full access' and have the user manually manage the shared folders.

Comment: You are worng! Dropbox API manages sharable links to folders(Files) and in addition appfolders can share folder(Files) inside it.. so you don't need to use "full access".. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#shares

Comment: No, actually, the API doesn't support 'shared folders' ( https://www.dropbox.com/help/19/en ), but it does support 'shareable links' ( https://www.dropbox.com/help/167/en ) including for folders. These are different features, and it sounds like the question was referring to 'shared folders'.

Comment: @Bala...Greg is right....My requirement is I want to share folder with specific dropbox users... dropbox link is actually web url for files or folder. Who so ever will have that link can access file.